# How to make Pycharm view pdf automatically after compiling latex file?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, latex

I'm using Texify plugin for Pycharm to write latex. After running, I have to go manually to "out" folder and open it with Adobe. How to make Pycharm do that automatically?

I see this option but I don't know how to fill it up.
[image]

Comment: You can try configuring [macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) if the plugin provides some related actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe locking the pdf file is a [well-known issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288470/how-do-i-open-pdf-in-adobe-reader-dc-without-locking-the-file-from-being-updated), and so Adobe is not supported by TeXiFy. Depending on which OS you are on, the following pdf viewers are supported (links to [TeXiFy wiki](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Features) pages):

- All: [internal PDF viewer](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Built-in-pdf-viewer-support), via the [PDF viewer plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14494-pdf-viewer).
- Windows: [SumatraPDF](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/SumatraPDF-support)
- Linux: [Evince](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Evince-support), [Okular](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Okular-support), and [Zathura](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Zathura-support)
- Mac: [Skim](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Skim-support)

where supported means that the pdf automatically opens on compilation and that forward and backward search should work, the latter possibly after some configuration.

When you want to use some other pdf viewer, make sure that it does not lock the pdf file (so Adobe is not possible) and enter the command you would use to open the viewer from the command line in the `Select custom pdf viewer command` field. This should work on (at least) most Linux and Mac distributions.

**Edit**
As of TeXiFy b0.7.4 the [internal PDF viewer](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Built-in-pdf-viewer-support) is supported through the [PDF viewer plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14494-pdf-viewer).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively there is a PDF Plugin, to open it within PyCharm, which you can install from the store.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14494-pdf-viewer